# Mule Inject for connectors

Tags: java, mule

Is it possibel to @Inject a mule connector in a Callable if i do this i get

> No qualifying bean [org.mule.modules.MyConnector ]

```
public class MyService implements Callable{

@Inject
MyConnector myConnector;

public Object onCall(MuleEventContext eventContext) throws Exception {
        myConnector.run();
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the mule context in connector, you should inject the mule context in your connector code.

@Inject

private MuleContext muleContext;

public void setMuleContext(final MuleContext muleContext) { this.muleContext = muleContext; }

In the method level you can inject MuleEventContext also.

PLEASE NOTE,
The above approach is correct for older DevKit versions (3.6.x and older)

- Since 3.7 you can inject the MuleEvent to your @Processor by adding a MuleEvent parameter type in your method, Devkit will inject automatically the event.
- Starting with 3.7, there is a new API in Mule called Injector which is capable of injecting dependencies into a JSR-330 annotated object. Injected instances do not go into the registry because of it.